# Blender shuts down after login screen

Tags: windows, system

Whenever system locks to windows login screens (either manualy by pressing <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> or after some inactivity period) Blender shuts down, even if there is rendering process going on.

Is there any way to prevent this? It looks like problem appear with recent versions, cause I don't remember anything like this before.

Comment: Try starting blender from a/the command/terminal window this way the next time it shuts down it may show an error or say if it has crashed at the command prompt.

Comment: Rick's suggestion is good.  Also note that there is a crash.txt created in /users/[login]/AppData/Local/Temp if the program is about to crash.